# How to Remove Special/Bad Characters from XML Using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have an XML Files and I want to remove those Hexadecimal Characters Errors from the file below is the invalid characters:

[image]

I don't know what does STX means and when i tried copying it to my clipboard and paste it in MS Work it shows some other value.

How can I write a script in powershell to remove the above from my XML file.

Comment: Those are ASCII [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character), `start of text 0x02` and `end of text 0x03`. As how to remove those, it really depends on the xml file contents.

Comment: @vonPryz is there any way to make a script to look for that error??

Comment: Is there a way to make a script? Sure there is. Will we write the script for you? Not very likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regex will remove any invalid characters from XML by specifying a character class negating the entire set of valid unicode entries in an XML document:

```
$rPattern = "[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\xD7FF\xE000-\xFFFD\x10000\x10FFFF]"
$xmlText -replace $rPattern,''
```

This can easily be turned into [a simple function](https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/6f4de981c9e179af699a#file-repair-xmlstring-ps1):

```
function Repair-XmlString
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
    [string]$inXML
  )

  # Match all characters that does NOT belong in an XML document
  $rPattern = "[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\xD7FF\xE000-\xFFFD\x10000\x10FFFF]"

  # Replace said characters with [String]::Empty and return
  return [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace($inXML,$rPattern,"")
}
```

Then do:

```
Repair-XmlString (Get-Content path\to\file.xml -Raw) |Set-Content path\to\file.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Update of function :)

```
function Repair-XmlString {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$String
    )
    Write-Host "Cleaning string for XML parsing [String: $($String)]"
    $rPattern = "[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\xD7FF\xE000-\xFFFD\x10000\x10FFFF]"
    $cleaned = $String -replace $rPattern, ''
    Write-Host "Returning parsed string [String cleaned: $($cleaned)]"
    return $cleaned
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Another way, No 'Repair-XmlString' function needed, just wrap the string in single quotes
# This is an example of exporting install software names that have foreign characters. 

# Wrap output string with foreign characters in single quotes
$InstalledSoftware = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ |  Get-ItemProperty | select @{n="DisplayName";e={"\`'$($_.DisplayName)\`'"}}, DisplayVersion  

# Create Hastable
$SoftwareHashTable = @{SoftwareName = $InstalledSoftware }
# Output file path
$outFile = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\HashFile.xml"   
# Export to hashtable xml                                                             
Export-Clixml -InputObject $SoftwareHashTable -Depth 4 -Path $outFile -Encoding UTF8 
# Import xml Hashtable
$ImportedXml = Import-Clixml $outFile    
# View values                                                                         
$ImportedXml.Values
```