# Remove XML encoding information with PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, encoding

I'm currently using TFS PowerTools to run a query in PowerShell and export the results as an XML file.  I then want to import that XML file into Alteryx for further processing.  When TFS PT exports the XML file it puts the following header at the top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

However Alteryx does not like this and refuses to read the document unless the encoding information is taken off.  Is there a way that I can use PowerShell to remove the encoding information so it only shows:

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
$doc = New-Object xml
$doc.Load((Resolve-Path ".\path\to\doc.xml").ProviderPath)
if($doc.FirstChild.NodeType -eq 'XmlDeclaration')
{
    $doc.FirstChild.Encoding = $null
}
$doc.Save((Resolve-Path ".\path\to\doc.xml").ProviderPath)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!  I inserted your code into my script and changed the file paths, however I'm getting the following error when I run the script:

Comment: Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 2, position 
1."

Comment: At C:\Users\RunQuery.ps1:29 char:1
+ $doc.Load((Resolve-Path ".\workItems.xml").ProviderPath)

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
 
Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid XML document. The document does not have a root element."
At C:\Users\RunQuery.ps1:34 char:1
+ $doc.Save((Resolve-Path ".\workItems.xml").ProviderPath)
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: @camruny sounds like your xml document is malformed (contains invalid unicode characters). Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706565/how-to-remove-special-bad-characters-from-xml-using-powershell/45708615#45708615)

Comment: Thank you!  That removed the encoding information, and I added the code that you attached to remove invalid characters.  It appears that hyphens are causing the issue now.  Any idea how I can modify the code you linked to include hyphens as well.  Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: @camruny Feel free to [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), I'd suggest you post the entire sample xml file

Answer (score 0):

This will work however the xml file is no longer valid.

```
$xml = get-content $xmlfile | Out-String
$xml = $xml.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>',"") #removes text
$xml | out-file $xmlfile #outputs text in file
```

Comment: While this [code may answer the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272), providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.