# Parsing atom files in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, atom-feed

I am trying to parse the Microsoft Windows 10 feed:

```
$feed = "https://support.microsoft.com/app/content/api/content/feeds/sap/en-us/6ae59d69-36fc-8e4d-23dd-631d98bf74a9/atom"
$resp = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$feed"
```

However converting the response to XML with  `[xml]($resp.Content)` gives an error.
An easy fix would be removing the initial (empty?) character:

```
[xml]($resp.Content.Substring(1))
```

Which is the correct  way, by the way?

Comment: if you replace the `Invoke-WebRequest` call with `Invoke-RestMethod` you will get back an array of `XmlElement` items. they seem to contain the info you likely want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments you can either let `Invoke-RestMethod` take care of the content parsing for you:

```
$atoms = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$feed"
```

or you could use the `-replace` regex operator to trim formatting characters off the beginning of the string:

```
$atomDoc = $resp.Content -replace '^\p{Cf}' -as [xml]
```

`\p{Cf}` matches any character that falls under the unicode Format category

---

If you're looking for a more comprehensive sanitation of your input string, you can also [remove *any character* that doesn't belong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45708615/712649) in an XML document:

```
$resp.Content -replace '[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\xD7FF\xE000-\xFFFD\x10000\x10FFFF]',''
```